# How to keep only the last part of column name regardless of the length of the columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df columns that looks like this:

```
string1_0_string2_string3          string2_0_0_1_string4
      1                                     1
```

I want to only keep the name after the last underscore `_` in the column name, how would I do this?

New df should look like this:

```
string3        string4
  1                1
```

Comment: why are you interested in this. you could `string2_x_x_stringx.split('_')[-1:]` @RustyShackleford

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.split`

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.split('_').str[-1]
df
Out[183]: 
   string3  string4
0        1        1
```

Comment: you can also use `rsplit` / specify `n`.